# What are the consequences of an item locked in the web database?

Tags: security

While reviewing if an item was published in the Web database, I noticed some items showed the locked gutter icon.

- Is there a change in behavior with respect to viewing the published site if an item is locked?
- Does the Access Result cache have any relationship to these locked items?
- Should I care if items are locked in the Web database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Lock is purely a mechanism used by the Editor interfaces. I has no bearing on any of the Apis, any of the caching or any other sort of effect on the live site running off "web".

One can't prove a negative, so I can't point you to a specific official document stating this. Take it from experience.